# How can I scan/test/explore if my Firefox (profile) has been infected?

Tags: security, firefox, troubleshooting

I use Debian and because of that the version in the reps is outdated, so I have Firefox Quantum that is fully unpacked in a folder where my non-root user has all permissions to read, write and execute.

I suspect that my browser (or profile) could have been infected with malware, but I have no idea how to do it, how to check specifically the browser.

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but Debian tracks [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/enterprise/), and always has the latest release which is fully-supported by Mozilla.

Comment: What is it that makes think your browser has been compromised?

Answer (score 0):

For the browser, it is pretty easy to remove the folder, download and install it again. Alternatively, you could download the current version and compare the two folders.

For the profile, usually malware comes via extensions, so you can run Firefox without them ([safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)) and see if the suspect behaviour still happens. Or you can [individually disabl](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons)e the ones you think could be the problem.

Comment: I use unsandboxed flash plugin, could malware infect the browser through it, theoretically speaking?

Comment: Theoretically speaking it could infect your whole system...

Answer (score 0):

Run in any terminal:

```
zip -r firefox.zip .mozilla
```

Upload firefox.zip to virustotal.com (mind that by doing that you'll share with them your browsing history, saved passwords and open website sessions).